# jquery mobile replace hyperlink with another hyperlink

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I am in the need of replacing a html "a" tag of a certain class with another a tag.

this is my code

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript"src="jquery.mobile-1.3.0"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.3.0" type="text/css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$('.list1').replaceWith('<a class="list3" href="#">link3</a>');
</script>

</head>

<body>

<h1> hello world </h1>

<div class="content-page" >
  <div class="list-page">
    <a class="list1" href="#">link1</a>
    <a class="list2" href="#">link2</a>  
  </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

I used the jquery replaceWith function but to my disappointment it didn't work for me in this case. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
<html>
<head>
    <!-- STYLESHEETS //-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <!-- JavaScripts //-->
    <script src="http://www.dragan-gaic.info/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>   
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.list1').replaceWith('<a class="list3" href="#">link3</a>');
    }); 
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<h1> hello world </h1>
<div class="content-page" >
  <div class="list-page">
    <a class="list1" href="#">link1</a>
    <a class="list2" href="#">link2</a>  
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

You need to wrap your code into document ready.

Or if you want jQuery Mobile version:

```
<html>
<head>
    <!-- STYLESHEETS //-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <!-- JavaScripts //-->
    <script src="http://www.dragan-gaic.info/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>   
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '.content-page', function() {
        $('.list1').replaceWith('<a class="list3" href="#">link3</a>');
    }); 
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<h1> hello world </h1>
<div class="content-page" data-role="page">
  <div class="list-page">
    <a class="list1" href="#">link1</a>
    <a class="list2" href="#">link2</a>  
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

**EDIT :**

In your example, replace these lines:

```
<script type="text/javascript"src="jquery.mobile-1.3.0"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.3.0" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
```

With this lines:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
<!-- JavaScripts //-->
<script src="http://www.dragan-gaic.info/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"</script>
```

Basically first initialize jQuery Mobile css, then initialize jQuery then initialize jQuery Mobile. In your example you are initializing jQuery Mobile before jQuery and that is probably causing the error.

Comment: when i used your jquery statement it didnt work. But when i copied your entire code it worked. What am i missing here ? :(

Comment: Are you talking about my first or second example?

Comment: both. When i replaced my jquery code lines with yours it doesnt work. Please help me.

Comment: I will add another segment into my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Also, it may be preferable to use the following after the DOM manipulation. This is done in order to apply back the JQuery mobile CSS to the elements.

```
    $(":jqmData(role='page')").trigger('create');
```

Or specifically

```
    $(".list-page").trigger('create');
```

if you want to refresh the CSS of the particular portion in your DOM.